# Tracking image clicks with google analytics?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up conversions using Google Analytics. What I want to define as a conversion is when a person clicks on certain images in my blog (product adverts). How can I do this in google analytics?

I found that you can track URL clicks, but the url the image leads to is offsite. Will that still work?

Comment: Your question body cuts off.

Answer (score 2):

You can track outbound links of any kind with Google Analytics using JavaScript.

See Google's help article on it, http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72712.

Answer (score 0):

For interactions such as clicking on product adverts that lead off-site, you'd be best of using [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html). You can use [virtual page views](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncMigrationExamples.html#VirtualPageviews), but Google recommends event tracking for this type of interaction.

Once you'd added the event tracking code to the links you want to track, you'll need to [setup those events as goals](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/how-to-use-events-goals-google-analytics/).